# How to create sharded table in GCP BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As we started working on GCP BigQuery, our code has to retrieve data from so called sharded table in a dataset. This table group is with the name seen like `sometablename_(3000)` with the icon represent as [image]. The number there in parenthesis represents total count of tables created in the dataset so far with the date, and everyday the tables are getting added there by some other publishers and the count increases daily thus. Our code needs a wildcard query to limit date range to read data from this table which works fine. Only other option we see while creating a table from console is partition table which is represented differently.

But curious question is how are these tables getting created daily in the first place? When we manually tried creating another table with same name format, it's getting created as separate table but getting into this group. Not sure if documentation has any reference but can't find any.

So any help in understanding this background is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, correct me if I'm wrong, but you are looking for ways trough code ... like using client libraries and perform an operation? or to make a procedure which will allow you to use that wildcard value to limit the output data.

Comment: About your question about how these tables are created, are you referring to create a table inside a dataset? Are you referring a dataset as group? or a new table out of group out of a table? what do you mean by table group you mention earlier? For info about dataset you can go to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#sql) If you can put some code or design will help me understand the picture of it.

Comment: Also, have try going to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables). Do you want to perform this dynamically??

Comment: Thanks @Betjens. Here are my questions in a nutshell 
(1) How are these tables getting created daily? How to create them on GCP Console? Are they being created through some code?
(2) I tried creating partitioned tables, but they show up differently on the GCP console, not like this table group, i.e. not like tablename_(count-of-tables).

Comment: In fact the Partitioned tables show up with different icon as well, not the one I gave in the post. Well Dataset is irrelevant here, any dataset is fine, but this question is only around these tables which are being shown as an array/group by the date.

Comment: So just to bring some light. Have you try open the table and then hove over details to see the characteristics of that special table. It would help identify what kind of table we are looking for. So when you create a partion table a new icon shows ( a table cut by half right? )

Comment: Yes, the partition table identifies itself differently, icon like you explained.
This table group is showing up differently, like the icon I gave above.
If I click to query on three dots on this table name, the latest timestamp table, like tablename_20211202 shows up with the SQL on the query window. I can still use _TABLE_SUFIX BETWEEN to get the results from all tables between a time window. But I am not able to understand how this is exactly showing up like a group in the explorer, what type of table this icon signify and how to create this! that's the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Sharded tables** are generated automatically once google-bigquery finds tables that share the following characteristics:

- Exist in the same dataset
- Have the exact same table schema
- The same prefix
- Have a suffix of the form _YYYYMMDD (eg. 20210130)

You can find additional info about sharded table on official documention, [Partitioning versus sharding](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard).

So, that means if I create 3 tables named BUSINES_YYYYMMDD it will be grouped once refreshed in the UI.

```
 * Business_(3)
    - Business_20211201
    - Business_20211202
    - Business_20211203
```

And if I want to query those tables I will just have to either go trough the ui and select the table.

```
# UI under schema tab 
BUSINESS_20211203      2021-12-03 v  # Filter tables under the shard

Table schema
...
```

Or just go directly to the query ui `compose new query` and perform a query.

```
   Select * from my-project-id.my-dataset.Business_20211203 limit 1
```

So if you are getting tables created by publishers/org inside the same dataset that fits the conditions mention at the top it will be grouped.

About querying this groups, google recommends to do partition instead of sharding. You can see the process of converting sharded into partion table by going to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#convert-date-sharded-tables).

Also, I found this [post](https://mark-mccracken.medium.com/bigquery-date-sharding-vs-date-partitioning-cee3754f7900) which also shows the vs of each mode.

Comment: uha! refreshing the browser was the key, I was totally stumped! Tried just now and the truth is revealed. Thanks much @Betjens for explaining it so clearly.

Comment: I was confused by the same thing. Refreshing the browser did the trick. Thanks OP! 