# Why does bigquery show the number (1) behind some tables

Tags: google-bigquery

After loading data with batch processing to Google BigQuery i'm expecting tables that are partitioned based on their date (I know, have to rename the column of date as it's reserved).

However, when receiving some new tables they have a different icon and show the number 1 behind the table in this format ***(1)***. See the image below.

What is happening here? I would expect them to be normal partitioned tables.
I can't find this anywhere in their documentation or the wider web.

// if you give a -1 at least tell me why? What is wrong with this question?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This number is shown there because it is probably that you used to have more tables with the same schema and the same name prefix, but now those tables are deleted. For example, here I have 6 tables with the same prefix and it shows (6).

[image]

When I open this table it appears that the I can select the other tables to show the schema or details as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jose. I found it now :) - when opening the table it that dropdown apears next to the table name at the top. RIght under the tabs of other tables/queries.

Comment: Do you know what this is called (it doesn't look like partitioning) or how to manually achieve this?

Leaving for others, it's called sharding, more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194094/how-to-create-sharded-table-in-gcp-bigquery